# Why the GC happens so frequent in Android?

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I have exit my app, but there is still a backgroud service is running. Whe the GC logs come a log. I will so you the logs beblow. You can see, about 3 logs per second. Is This phenomenon is normal ? My device's memory is enough, and the backgroud service is holding a WebSocket connection.

```
08-11 10:33:54.456    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2020K, 18% free 10682K/12871K, paused 12ms+6ms, total 44ms
08-11 10:33:54.776    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1985K, 18% free 10676K/12871K, paused 12ms+8ms, total 54ms
08-11 10:33:55.109    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1950K, 18% free 10671K/12871K, paused 12ms+17ms, total 68ms
08-11 10:33:55.459    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2004K, 18% free 10680K/12871K, paused 13ms+8ms, total 62ms
08-11 10:33:55.769    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2010K, 18% free 10680K/12871K, paused 12ms+7ms, total 48ms
08-11 10:33:56.093    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1996K, 18% free 10677K/12871K, paused 12ms+9ms, total 50ms
08-11 10:33:56.416    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2028K, 18% free 10681K/12871K, paused 2ms+8ms, total 37ms
08-11 10:33:56.746    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2031K, 18% free 10682K/12871K, paused 8ms+8ms, total 46ms
08-11 10:33:57.079    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1996K, 18% free 10677K/12871K, paused 12ms+7ms, total 46ms
08-11 10:33:57.429    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2002K, 18% free 10678K/12871K, paused 12ms+19ms, total 59ms
08-11 10:33:57.766    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2003K, 18% free 10679K/12871K, paused 12ms+7ms, total 46ms
08-11 10:33:58.143    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1945K, 18% free 10669K/12871K, paused 12ms+17ms, total 72ms
08-11 10:33:58.473    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2020K, 18% free 10682K/12871K, paused 2ms+6ms, total 41ms
08-11 10:33:58.786    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2013K, 17% free 10690K/12871K, paused 12ms+8ms, total 48ms
08-11 10:33:59.106    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2031K, 18% free 10683K/12871K, paused 12ms+8ms, total 53ms
08-11 10:33:59.443    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2021K, 18% free 10681K/12871K, paused 12ms+8ms, total 48ms
08-11 10:33:59.786    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2028K, 18% free 10681K/12871K, paused 11ms+7ms, total 44ms
08-11 10:34:00.153    6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1997K, 18% free 10677K/12871K, paused 12ms+18ms, total 58ms
```

Comment: Depends on what the service is doing. Show code or provide more detail.

Comment: My device's memory is enough, and the backgroud service is holding a WebSocket connection.

Comment: Didn't notice the frequency of GC. When I ask for more detail I really mean more detail. You say your service is holding a WebSocket connection. How and with what library and for what reason. Details like this help others understand your problem and can suggest solutions. With what you've given StephenC's answer is the best response. Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

> Is This phenomenon is normal ?

It depends what you mean by "normal".

If you mean normal for an application with those particular heap dimensions, that amount of heapspace used for long-lived objects, and that rate of allocation ... then the answer is "Yes, it is normal".

Basically, you are running your application with a heap that is (objectively) too small for the work that you are asking it to do.  You have roughly 2Mb of free space, and you are allocating objects at roughly 6Gb per second.  If you want to reduce the number of GC cycles, you need to do one or more of the following:

- Increase the heap size.  (I don't know if this is feasible for an Android app ...)
- Reduce the "working set" of long-lived objects.  Maybe you have a memory leak, lots of large images loaded, or an overly large in-memory cache of ... something.
- Reduce the rate at which new objects are being allocated by your application.

The last two require you to track down the source of the memory usage / allocation, and change you code to mitigate the effects.  There are tools (memory profilers) that can help with this, but the details will be specific to your application.

---

Here's how I'd interpret the GC log lines ... by example:

```
08-11 10:33:54.456 6821-6823/com.tong.iknow:ik_service_v1 E/dalvikvm﹕ 
GC_CONCURRENT freed 2020K, 18% free 10682K/12871K, paused 12ms+6ms, total 44ms
```

1. The "GC_CONCURRENT" collector is being used.
2. This GC collection cycle reclaimed 2020K bytes.
3. When the GC cycle completed, 18% of the heap is free, and 10682K out of a total usable heap size of 12871K is in use.
4. Normal thread activity was paused for two intervals of 12ms and 6ms respectively.
5. The elapsed time for the GC cycle was 44ms.

Note that the amount of heap freed isn't always exactly the same as the different between total and available ... because for much of the time that the GC is running there are normal threads allocating new objects.

Comment: is 10683K/12871K means: (used mem)/(total mem or heap size) ?